# How to build an IOS application that works even when the user closes it

Tags: ios

I'm new to the world of iOS programming.

My goal is to build an application that works even when it's in the background and even when the user eventually closes it, as its purpose is to send data to my web page.

After building the application and making it work in the background, I started searching on the Internet how to make the application work for iOS even when the user closes it.

Starting from the fact that I also developed in Android, I started to do research with the following keywords (service / swift / ios) and I learned that in iOS it is not possible to have an application that works as a 'service' as it happens on Android.

So I wonder, how do applications like Gmail, WhatsApp, iMessage, Telegram work even when they are not active in iOS multitasking?

Comment: What kind of data will you be sending? e.g is it location data that the app will need to continually sample from the LocationManager?

Comment: Yes, I send a sequence of data including the position data sampled by LocationManager

Comment: You can use the significant location change to wake the app up periodically so that it can record the location and send it to your backend - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service

Comment: Would you have any links I can study?

Comment: There's one in my comment above

Comment: Thanks from device, I hadn't seen it

Comment: I also read some data transmitted by iBeacon, such an extended position would not help me much. There is a risk that some iBeacons will be at a distance of 10/20 meters and the application should continue to scan them

Comment: "My goal is to build an application that works even when it's in the background and even when the user eventually closes it, as its purpose is to send data to my web page." Give up your goal. A killed app cannot "do" any "work". You can arrange for your app to be woken periodically for a lengthy network or background task, but you can't count on that. iMessage is obviously special because Apple gets to run its own daemon. What makes you think something like Gmail works after being killed?

Answer (score 0):

If the user merely "closes" an app by switching to another app, or locking their iPhone, then iOS APIs such as URLSessionDownloadTask will continue to download data in the background.  Apps that play background audio also continue to run when an app is merely closed (but not killed).

However, none of these app tasks will run if a user force closes an app (swipes up in the Springboard launcher).